# Toggle visibility of multiple table-rows with specified <tr class="xxx"> by button (more/less details)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

There are tons of jQuery accordions to toggle single rows or lines. But i need one, which can toggle multiple table-rows with a specified TR-class (tr class="xxx") by an "show more/less details"-button at once.

I want to start, showing a table with basic information only (few rows). On button-click, the hidden rows between the invisible ones should be shown.

Can't find anything like that.

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: Show what you've tried and why it didn't work. You'll get better results that way than just asking someone to write it for you.

Comment: `$('tr.xxx').slideToggle('slow')`

Comment: Thanks Pavel. There is still no specific code, but I will post an example. I'm looking for an approach...